# How some Apps can track location even if the App is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I track location using CLLocationManager and it's delegate

```
_locationManager = [ CLLocationManager new ];
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
_locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
```

How can I update the code to track location when App is closed. How does the App track locations and send a local notification when I want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could request your app to run in background mode by adding the following key in info.plist file.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this be used when App is terminated but not minimized?